# Get current color

Tags: c++, opengl

Im using `glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha_);` to set transparency to primitives I'm drawing.

However I'd like to be able to read the current opengl alpha value. Is that possible?

e.g.

```
float current_alpha = glGetAlpha(); //???
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, alpha_*current_alpha);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either you store the last alpha value you sent using `glColor4f`, either you use:

```
float currentColor[4];
glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_COLOR,currentColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the alpha value of the fragment you're drawing on (which would explain why you want `alpha_ * current_alpha`)? If so, remember that reading a fragment back from the pipeline is *expensive*.

If you're rendering back to front, consider using the [GL_SRC_ALPHA + GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA](http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2010/02/alpha-blending-back-to-front-front-to.html) trick.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to do something similar.